# Import text file to postgresql permission denied

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to import data from a text file into a table. The table is empty but the schema is there. I run the command

`\copy tbl_windspeed from '/home/~~~myname~~~~/Documents/csv_windspeed.txt'`

It tells me `Permission denied`. I check the file's permissions and even set it to chmod 777 so it's now `-rwxrwxrwx`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I even tried restarting the server? `service postgresql restart`

Comment: Where and how do you run that statement? `\copy` is a command specific to Postgres' command line client `psql`. Are you using that?

Comment: as @a_horse_with_no_name says - `\copy` looks for a file of client side, not server - where you checked permissions?..

Comment: permission denied can refers to each directory in the path

Comment: @jack: no, `\copy` runs as the user that started `psql` (it's a client side command, not server side)

Comment: ok @a_horse_with_no_name - I read it from your previous comment and edited mine. thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes I ran the \copy command from the postgres command line. The permissions that I tested are for a file that is on my personal computer, not on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why this worked but I found a solution:

I was logged in as "postgres" and I guess it didn't like that. I created a new user with login, and created that database and tables through that user (so it has owner privileges). Since that new user I created had the same username as my linux user name, I think that's why I was able to import that file.

Can I not use the user "postgres" to import files on my laptop? When I login to psql I login through `sudo -u postgres -i`, I have to put in a password. So, it knows I am authenticated as the root user. If someone could give me some more info or explain why that is the case that would be appreciated.